# Forms created dynamically events

Tags: jquery, forms, events

im new in this, so questions are:

im creating forms with a loop

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var html = "";
  var num = "";
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    html = '<form id="form' + i + 'p">';
    html = html + '<input type="text" name="text' + i + '" id="text' + i + '">';
    html = html + '<button type="submit" id ="' + i + '" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>';
    html = html + '</form>';

    $('#test').append(html);
  }

  $("button").click(function() {
    console.log("entre");
    var num = '#form' + $(this).attr('id') + 'p';
    alert(num);
  });

  $('#form' + num + 'p"').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("in");
  });
});
```

when i try to do a submit of any of forms, the event doesnt exist, but if i create a specific submit event does work example: `$('#form1p').submit(function (e) {......`

what can i do to do submit of any of them and send the data to another page? or is there another way to do it.

Comment: The double quote doesn't belong here `$('#form'+num+'p"')`. You're also missing a closing `)` from the document.ready. Aside from that, [it seems to work](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/d2eyj1kg/1/)

Comment: fixed but still doesn't work

Comment: Works in the example I made. What errors are you getting in the console?

Comment: Nothing in console, nothing happen, even page refresh after submit and de alert(in) doesnt show up